# Create similar Dialog when clicking different buttons

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialog

Background:
I have 4 buttons in the activity.

What I want to achieve:
Clicking on each button displays the exact same Dialog with a list of 5 items. Clicking on an item in the list invokes a method (which is defined in the activity) that takes 2 parameters:

1. a value indicating which of the 4 buttons was initially clicked
2. a value indicating which of the 5 items in the list is chosen

That is all I want to achieve. I think it is a pretty common scenario but I can't find any solution after searching for awhile.

I am trying to follow the Android developer API guide:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

If I follow the guide, I will have something like this:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
           .setItems(R.array.dialog_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // something
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to pass a value indicating which button was clicked into the `onClick` method. Of course one way is to create 4 different DialogFragment, each for each button, but I believe that should be a way cleaner than this. My first thought is to create a DialogFragment Factory and return different anonymous DialogFragment for different inputs for the factory, but the compiler complains, stating "Fragments should be static", apparently because of some life cycle management issue. When I am searching around, I encounter some examples using `onCreateDialog` that I think can solve my problem, but apparently this method is deprecated...

I have no idea now (except to create 4 different DialogFragment). Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The first idea that come in my mind right now, is to pass an integer to the constructor of `MyDialogFragment` and when you click on first button you will call `new MyDialogFragment(1)` and inside constructor you will have something like `public void MyDialogFragment(int whichWasSelected){this.whichWasSelected = whichWasSelected;}`

Answer (score 0):

### You can do it with the opposite logic

I have a similar stuff, and I solved it by using a static method which creates a dialog and an interface for retrieving the result:

**This is my static method**

```
public static void showGenericItemSelectorDialog(Activity activity, ArrayList<MyParams> items, final IReturnMyListItemToParent iReturnMyListItemToParent) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_searchable_list, null); //or init it howerer you want, I have a custom layout
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    /// omitted not useful code

    Button myBtn= (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
    myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //check which item has been clicked
            iReturnMyListItemToParent.onResult(myClickedItem);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            iReturnMyListItemToParent.onResult(null);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

**This is my interface**

```
public interface IReturnMyListItemToParent {
    void onResult(MyItem item);
}
```

**This is how I call it:**

```
RuntimeHelper.showGenericItemSelectorDialog(getActivity(), myParams, new IReturnMyListItemToParent() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResult(MyItem result) {
                                      //do stuff with that result item clicked
                                    }
                                });
```

This is an example, but this way you can do whatever you want just by calling the static method from each button.

### If you want to keep your logic:

This way I changed your "pass button to adapter" with passing result to button.

If you want to pass the button to the method, just add a parameter in the constructor that points you to the clicked button :)

Hope this helps